# Have lines crossed!

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning, comprehension

I couldn't understand the meaning of have lines crossed in the sentence below:

"We must have had our lines crossed, thank you for checking."

I'd appreciate it if you help me in this order.

Thanks

Comment: It seems "crossed lines" is some kind of fault, but without context maybe no one can tell you what it means.

Comment: I think the phrase is usually "gotten our _wires_ crossed".

Answer (score 2):

It means there's been miscommunication. The expression began quite literally where the crossing of lines used to occur with telephone calls (see comment below), which resulted in disturbances (odd dial tones, hearing other peoples conversations etc.)

> Person 1: I thought we were meeting on the 20th?
>
> Person 2: No, I definitely said the 30th.
>
> Person 1: Sorry, I guess my lines were crossed. The 30th it is.

Comment: You're right about the telephony origin, but the wires got crossed at the operator's switchboard as the operator physically used patch cables to connect the caller to the receiver, not out on the poles.  And the crossing was the accidental placement of a cable into the wrong plug on the switchboard rather than some static interference.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Jim. I have no idea why my mind went to telephone pole wires haha.

Answer (score -1):

Having your lines crossed goes back to teamsters and wagons.  If they connected the lines incorrectly to the horse teams, when they pulled in one direction the horse would be led in the other direction.  Having your lines crossed would make you steer the horses in the wrong direction, the horses couldn't understand you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [This source](https://wordhistories.net/2019/02/10/get-wires-crossed/) says "crossed wires" originated in telegraphy in the 1860s; I'd be surprised if "crossed lines", having essentially the same meaning, has a different origin. Do you have a citation or reference?